# Docker on W10 and Hyper-V "no Procfile path defined"

Tags: docker, hyper-v, divio

I am an Aldryn customer and have troubles to setup their docker environment with Windows 10 and Hyper-V. 
Before I used Virtualbox and all was fine, but I could not use interactive shells.
So I really would like to make the switch to Hyper-V.
My docker version Client is: 1.12.0 and I use *cmder* as my terminal.

I run the `aldryn project setup` and then do

```
C:\Users\Hans\myproject [develop +1 ~1 -0 !]
λ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
973098beb1cb        myproject_web       "/tini -g -- start mi"   3 minutes ago       Exited (1) 3 minutes ago                       myproject_web_run_1  
e2f7faa6d8f8        postgres:9.4        "/docker-entrypoint.s"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes               5432/tcp            myproject_db_1
```

-

```
C:\Users\Hans\myproject [develop +1 ~1 -0 !]
λ docker logs 973098beb1cb
no Procfile path defined  <<-- this is the error message it's about
```

My project locally is at `C:\Users\Hans\myproject`
Then I check within the container:

```
C:\Users\Hans\myproject [develop +1 ~1 -0 !
λ docker run -i -t myproject_web /bin/bash
root@ed8410007425:/app# ls
Dockerfile  addons-dev    data.tar.gz                 gulpfile.js  package.json     requirements.txt  static            tools
Procfile    bower.json    docker-compose-windows.yml  manage.py    private          settings.py       static_collected  urls.py
addons      browserslist  docker-compose.yml          migrate.sh   requirements.in  settings.pyc      templates         wsgi.py
```

More info:

```
C:\Users\Hans\myproject [develop +1 ~1 -0 !]
λ docker-compose -f  docker-compose-windows.yml up
myproject_db_1 is up-to-date
Starting myproject_web_1
Attaching to myproject_db_1, myproject_web_1
web_1  | python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Aldryn does not have Windows experts, so they cannot support Windows users.
I hope there are fellow Windows users that might have solved this.

Where does this 'no Procfile path defined' come from?
Could it be a permission problem?
How do I debug this problem?

Comment: is it Aldryn Django?

Comment: Yes, Aldryn Django as well